# Prevent duplcate ajaxLoad event calls added with a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using MVC Razor - The overall goal is to create a "print view" pop-up page.

The print view button is on the parent page, when clicked, an ajax event is fired which will populate an empty div with the contents that are to be included in the print preview:

```
//from the view
@Ajax.ActionLink("prntPreview", "Display", new { ID = Model.Detail.ID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "modal" }, new { @class = "btnPreview" })
```

then, using JavasScript/jQuery I clone the contents of that newly populated div and create a new window with the contents:

```
//in the scripts file
$('.btnPreview').on('click', function () {
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        var pageData = $('#modal').html();
        setTimeout( //add a slight delay
            function () {
                PopupPrint(pageData);
            }, 300);
    });
});

function PopupPrint(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=800,resizable,scrollbars');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.focus();
    //do some other stuff here
}
```

This is where I run into difficulty. The first time I click, everything is working as expected - however, if you do not navigate away from the parent page and try to use the print preview button a second time, the popup will be created twice, then three times etc. with each additional click.

I think that the problem is because each time the `.btnPreview` is clicked, a new `$(document).ajaxStop` event is being created, causing the event to fire multiple times.

I have tried to create the ajaxStop as a named function which is declared outside the scope of the click event and then clear it but this produces the same result:

```
var evnt = "";
$('.btnPreview').on('click', function () {
    evnt = 
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        var pageData = $('#modal').html();
        setTimeout( //add a slight delay
            function () {
                PopupPrint(pageData);
                evnt = "";
            }, 300);
    });
});
```

I also have other `ajaxStop` events initialised so don't want to completely unbind the ajaxStop event. Is it possible to get the name or something from each ajax event so that I can clear just that event or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 issues which I needed to address. 
The answer is to unbind the ajax event after it has checked that the request had completed and to unbind and reattach the button click trigger.

This is how I did it:

```
//in the scripts file
$('.btnPreview').off('click').on('click', function () {

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (e) {
        var pageData = $('#modal').html();
        setTimeout( //add a slight delay
        function () {
            PopupPrint(pageData);
        }, 300);
        $(this).off(e);
    });

});
```

I unbound the click event by adding `.off('click')` before the `.on`. this is what stopped it popping up multiple times.

The other issue was that anytime any ajax event completed (triggered by something else) that would also create the popup - to get around that, I added `$(this).unbind(e);` to the end of the code block which removed the ajaxComplete binding which was being triggered each time any ajax event completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent adding additional triggers by checking with a variable outside of scope like this:

```js
(function() {
  var alreadyAdded = false;
  $('.btnPreview').on('click', function() {
    if (!alreadyAdded) {
      $('.eventTrigger').click(function() {
        console.log('printing!');
      });
      alreadyAdded = true;
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnPreview">Add Event</button>
<button class="eventTrigger">Trigger</button>
```

Please note that the variable and function are encapsulated in a self-executing anonymous function and do not pollute global space.

The output of the sample can be seen in the developer console. If you remove the if-check then every click on the "Add Event" button produces an additional print statement on the "Trigger" button each time it is clicked (which is your problem). With the if, there will ever only be one event on the trigger button.

Comment: This approach will allow me to check if the hidden div has been populated meaning that I would not need to wait for the ajax a second time. however, each time I click on the print preview button, I must wait until an ajax event has fired because that is getting the updated  contents to include in the preview. After the preview is printed the contents of the hidden div will be removed (as it will shortly expire).